# Why discord can't find role?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a role and give this role to a user.
This is my code:

```js
msg.guild.createRole({
  name: msg.author.username,
  color: "#ff0000",
})
const role = msg.guild.roles.find(role => role.name = msg.author.username)
msg.member.addRole(role)
```

And I have this error

```
(node:5776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Role
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: you seem to be using discord.js@v11, so my answer will be for that version*

That's because [`Guild.createRoles()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=createRole) is asynchronous: it returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and so you have to wait for it to be complete.
Here's how you can do it:

```js
msg.guild.createRole({
  name: msg.author.username, 
  color: "#ff0000"
}).then(role => {
  // You don't even need to search for it, since the role is what the Promise resolves to
  msg.member.addRole(role)
})
```

Comment: <3 Thank you
Maybe you know how to create a channel that only this role will see?

Comment: @Skiuel I think it's better if you open a second question, since this would be a more complex topic. If this answer solved your problem you can accept it by clicking the tick on the left: this way your question will be marked as answered and everybody will know that it's "closed"